# Javascript variables from PHP to JS file ERROR

Tags: javascript, php

JS & PHP file as follows

```js
console.log(my_val_json);
```

```html
<script async src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/java.js"></script>
<?php $my_php_val = array( 'banana', 'orange'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_val_json = '<?php echo json_encode($my_php_val); ?>' ;
</script>
```

Upon refreshing the page multiple times, i get the below error in my console log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: my_val_json is not defined
```

And sometimes this error also appears on the 1st load.
Please advice as i am unable to find any answers online for 2 days now. Thanks!

** NOTE: when i change async to defer, there are no errors (so far) **

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var my_val_json = '<?php echo json_encode($my_php_val);?>';`? (note the quotes).

Comment: @D4V1D : Stackoverflow removed it for some reason when i copied and pasted.

Comment: <? php - the space in between. is it a typo?

Comment: What is `java.js` used for?

Comment: @D4V1D : java.js is to write all my Javascripts but sometimes the variables doesnt seem to get the value specified in the PHP and sometime s it does. Currently the entire java.js has the above code  "console.log(my_val_json)"

Comment: @Vishal: Stackoverflow copy and paste error.

Comment: So you do `console.log(my_val_json);` **before** actually setting `my_val_json` to `<?php echo json_encode($my_php_val);?>`? If so, that is where you error lays.

Comment: try removing the var from 'var my_val_json' once

Comment: @D4V1D : Nope. The php file then the js file. But i guess that the js (at times) is loading faster (or from cached) then the php , therefore the error. As stated, when i add "DEFER", the error doesnt appear. But this ultimately defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Vishal : Nope, didnt work. I tried window.my_val_json as well and same issue. Sometime loads and sometime it doesnt.

Comment: see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227763/using-async-not-working-is-not-defined]

Comment: @Vishal: Thanks man! This is the correct solution, but let me try this out first.

Comment: @DJB: go ahead :) and if it works give that answer an upvote.

Comment: @Vishal: The solution is good but it loads the files one after the other, which slows the page load after DOM Loaded. However i tried "window.onload = function () {
console.log(my_val_json);
}" and so far, there isnt any errors. Keeping my fingers crosses while hitting the F5 repeatedly.